# one to many relationship entity framework required in two side

Tags: c#, entity-framework

how to make relation between two tables one to many and required in two sides
for example
i have project and image table 
every image has project And every project has at least one image 
i make this 
every image has project

```
public class ImageMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Image>
{
    public ImageMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("ProjectImage");
        this.HasKey<int>(i => i.Id);
        this.Property(i => i.ImagePath).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(2000);
        this.HasRequired<Project>(i => i.Project).WithMany(p => p.Images)
            .HasForeignKey(i => i.ProjectId);
    }
}
```

how make every project has at least one image or many ??? (Entity Framwork version 6)

Comment: If you can't do it in SQL, EF won't have a configuration option. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101048/how-to-enforce-that-one-row-in-a-parent-table-must-be-associated-with-at-least-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't ensure a "at least one" condition in the "many" part of a one to many relationship. This is not something you can manage in a db, without a check constraint, for example (you could also do a validation in your application to manage that).

One way to achieve that could be to create a one-to-one relationship AND a one-to-many, both pointing on the same table / entity.

So your Project would have a `MandatoryImage` property, for example, and a `AlternativeImages` (collection) property.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is something you should control in your Business Logic or Data Access layer before call `SaveChanges` method of your context. As far I know there is no way to configure that using Fluent API. So you could do something like this:

```
if(project.Images.Count()>0)// Or project.Images.Any()
{
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```